# New In-App Purchase template in Xcode 6.1 defaults to OS X target

Tags: xcode, templates, in-app-purchase, xcode6, setup-project

When creating a new project, I select iOS ->  Other -> In-App Purchase.

[image]

However, every time a new project is created, I end up with a IAP for OS X:

[image]

Does anyone know of a workaround/solution?

Comment: What is in these templates? The only IAP project I created was without a template. Can you create this "by hand"?

Comment: I'm not sure - there's a bunch of settings and stuff specially for an IAP package. Not sure how to replicate them all by hand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, to resolve it I went into build settings and in the architectures section I changed the base SDK from OS X to IOS 8.1 (latest) and changed supported platforms to IOS.